# How to update the weights of a composite model composed of pytorch and torch-geometric?

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I made a composite model `MainModel` which consist of a `GinEncoder` and a `MainModel` which containing some `Linear` layers, and the `GinEncoder` made by the package `torch-geometric`, show as following codes :

```py
class GinEncoder(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GinEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.gin_convs = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        self.gin_convs.append(GINConv(Sequential(Linear(1, 4),
                                                 BatchNorm1d(4), ReLU(),
                                                 Linear(4, 4), ReLU())))
        self.gin_convs.append(GINConv(Sequential(Linear(4, 4),
                                                 BatchNorm1d(4), ReLU(),
                                                 Linear(4, 4), ReLU())))


    def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch_node_id):
        # Node embeddings
        nodes_emb_layers = []
        for i in range(2):
            x = self.gin_convs[i](x, edge_index)
            nodes_emb_layers.append(x)

        # Graph-level readout
        nodes_emb_pools = [global_add_pool(nodes_emb, batch_node_id) for nodes_emb in nodes_emb_layers]

        # Concatenate and form the graph embeddings
        graph_embeds = torch.cat(nodes_emb_pools, dim=1)
        return graph_embeds


    def get_embeddings(self, x, edge_index, batch_node_id):
        with torch.no_grad():
            graph_embeds = self.forward(x, edge_index, batch_node_id).reshape(-1)

        return graph_embeds


class MainModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, graph_encoder:torch.nn.Module):
        super(MainModel, self).__init__()
        self.graph_encoder = graph_encoder
        self.lin1 = Linear(8, 4)
        self.lin2 = Linear(4, 8)


    def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch_node_id):
        graph_embeds = self.graph_encoder(x, edge_index, batch_node_id)
        out_lin1 = self.lin1(graph_embeds)
        pred = self.lin2(out_lin1)[-1]

        return pred

gin_encoder = GinEncoder().to("cuda")
model =  MainModel(gin_encoder).to("cuda")
```

I found that the weights of `GinEncoder` were not updated, while the weights of `Linear` layer in `MainModel` were updated.I observe this by following codes:

```py
gin_encoder = GinEncoder().to("cuda")
model =  MainModel(gin_encoder).to("cuda")
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters())
epochs = 

for epoch_i in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0

    for batch_i, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        data.to("cuda")
        x, x_edge_index, x_batch_node_id = data.x, data.edge_index, data.batch
        y, y_edge_index, y_batch_node_id = data.y[-1].x, data.y[-1].edge_index, torch.zeros(data.y[-1].x.shape[0], dtype=torch.int64).to("cuda")
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        graph_embeds_pred = model(x, x_edge_index, x_batch_node_id)
        y_graph_embeds = model.graph_encoder.get_embeddings(y, y_edge_index, y_batch_node_id)
        loss =  criterion(graph_embeds_pred, y_graph_embeds)
        train_loss += loss
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        if batch_i == 0:
            print(f"NO. {epoch_i} EPOCH")
            print(f"MainModel weights in epoch_{epoch_i}_batch0:{next(islice(model.parameters(), 15, 16))}", end="\n\n")
            print(f"GinEncoder weights in epoch_{epoch_i}_batch0:{next(model.graph_encoder.parameters())}")
            print("*"*80)
```

Outputs of codes:

```
NO. 0 EPOCH
MainModel weights in epoch_0_batch0:Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.1447, -0.3689, -0.2840, -0.3619, -0.2040,  0.2430,  0.4651,  0.3736],
       device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)

GinEncoder weights in epoch_0_batch0:Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.8312],
        [-0.5712],
        [-0.6963],
        [-0.1601]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
********************************************************************************
NO. 1 EPOCH
MainModel weights in epoch_1_batch0:Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.1842, -0.3333, -0.3170, -0.3247, -0.2424,  0.2627,  0.4272,  0.4119],
       device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)

GinEncoder weights in epoch_1_batch0:Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.8312],
        [-0.5712],
        [-0.6963],
        [-0.1601]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
********************************************************************************
NO. 2 EPOCH
MainModel weights in epoch_2_batch0:Parameter containing:
tensor([-0.2302, -0.3077, -0.3251, -0.2905, -0.2847,  0.2558,  0.3881,  0.4527],
       device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)

GinEncoder weights in epoch_2_batch0:Parameter containing:
tensor([[-0.8312],
        [-0.5712],
        [-0.6963],
        [-0.1601]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
********************************************************************************
```

My question is how to make `loss.backward()` and `optimizer.step()` also pass to `GinEncoder`?

PS.

- I put the complete codes in here: https://gist.github.com/theabc50111/3ca708d0c1101d57b6172bd717302710
- I put the training data on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_KMwCzf1diwS4gGNdSSxG7bnemqQkFxI?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that pytorch geometrics architecture requires for the GinEncoder module to be initialized inside the init function of MainModel. Therefore I would try to do:

```py
class MainModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self).__init__()
        self.graph_encoder = GinEncoder()
        self.lin1 = Linear(8, 4)
        self.lin2 = Linear(4, 8)
```

If you really want to parametrize the model you can also pass the GinEncoder as follows:

```
model =  MainModel(GinEncoder).to("cuda")
```

and

```py
class MainModel(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, graph_encoder:torch.nn.Module):
        super(self).__init__()
        self.graph_encoder = graph_encoder()
        self.lin1 = Linear(8, 4)
        self.lin2 = Linear(4, 8)
```

Comment: Thank you for your patience in reading my question.

I have tried to directly call `GinEncoder()` inside the `MainModel.__init__()`, but the parameters of `GinEncoder()` are still not change.