# Why are the weights not updating when splitting the model into two `class` in pytorch and torch-geometric?

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I tried two different ways to build my model:

- First approach: split the model into two `class`, one is `MainModel()` and the other is `GinEncoder()`, and when I call the `MainModel()`, it would also call `GinEncoder()` too.
- Second approach: Create a single class: `MainModel2()` by merging the two classes: `MainModel()` and `GinEncoder()`.

So the model layer structure of `MainModel2()` are as same as 『`MainModel()` + `GinEncoder()`』, but:

- In the first approach, **the weights of `GinEncoder()` cannot be updated*, while the weights of `MainModel()` can be updated.
- In the second approach, **all weights** of `MainModel2()` can be updated

My question is:
Why are the weights not updating when splitting the model into two `class` in pytorch and torch-geometric?  But when I merge the layers of these two classes, all weight can be updated?

Here are partial codes:

- First approach: split the model to two `class`, one is `MainModel`, the other `GinEncoder`, as shown as below:

  ```py
  class GinEncoder(torch.nn.Module):
      def __init__(self):
          super(GinEncoder, self).__init__()
          self.gin_convs = torch.nn.ModuleList()
          self.gin_convs.append(GINConv(Sequential(Linear(1, dim_h), ReLU(),
                                                   Linear(dim_h, dim_h), ReLU(),
                                                   BatchNorm1d(dim_h))))
          for _ in range(gin_layer-1):
              self.gin_convs.append(GINConv(Sequential(Linear(dim_h, dim_h), ReLU(),
                                                       Linear(dim_h, dim_h), ReLU(),
                                                       BatchNorm1d(dim_h))))


      def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch_node_id):
          # Node embeddings
          nodes_emb_layers = []
          for i in range(gin_layer):
              x = self.gin_convs[i](x, edge_index)
              nodes_emb_layers.append(x)

          # Graph-level readout
          nodes_emb_pools = [global_add_pool(nodes_emb, batch_node_id) for nodes_emb in nodes_emb_layers]

          # Concatenate and form the graph embeddings
          graph_embeds = torch.cat(nodes_emb_pools, dim=1)
          return graph_embeds


  class MainModel(torch.nn.Module):
      def __init__(self, graph_encoder:torch.nn.Module):
          super(MainModel, self).__init__()
          self.graph_encoder = graph_encoder
          self.lin1 = Linear(dim_h*gin_layer, 4)
          self.lin2 = Linear(4, dim_h*gin_layer)


      def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch_node_id):
          graph_embeds = self.graph_encoder(x, edge_index, batch_node_id)
          out_lin1 = self.lin1(graph_embeds)
          pred = self.lin2(out_lin1)[-1]

          return pred
  ```
- Second approach: create `MainModel2()` by merging layers of the two class: `MainModel()` and `GinEncoder()`

  ```py
  class MainModel2(torch.nn.Module):
      def __init__(self):
          super(MainModel2, self).__init__()
          self.gin_convs = torch.nn.ModuleList()
          self.gin_convs.append(GINConv(Sequential(Linear(1, dim_h), ReLU(),
                                                   Linear(dim_h, dim_h), ReLU(),
                                                   BatchNorm1d(dim_h))))
          self.gin_convs.append(GINConv(Sequential(Linear(dim_h, dim_h), ReLU(),
                                                   Linear(dim_h, dim_h), ReLU(),
                                                   BatchNorm1d(dim_h))))
          self.lin1 = Linear(dim_h*gin_layer, 4)
          self.lin2 = Linear(4, dim_h*gin_layer)


      def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch_node_id):
          # Node embeddings
          nodes_emb_layers = []
          for i in range(2):
              x = self.gin_convs[i](x, edge_index)
              nodes_emb_layers.append(x)

          # Graph-level readout
          nodes_emb_pools = [global_add_pool(nodes_emb, batch_node_id) for nodes_emb in nodes_emb_layers]

          # Concatenate and form the graph embeddings
          graph_embeds = torch.cat(nodes_emb_pools, dim=1)
          out_lin1 = self.lin1(graph_embeds)
          pred = self.lin2(out_lin1)[-1]

          return pred
  ```

PS.

- I put the complete codes in here:
  https://gist.github.com/theabc50111/8a38b88713f494be1d92d4ea2bdecc5e
- I put the training data on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_KMwCzf1diwS4gGNdSSxG7bnemqQkFxI?usp=sharing
- I asked a related question: [How to update the weights of a composite model composed of pytorch and torch-geometric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444625/how-to-update-the-weights-of-a-composite-model-composed-of-pytorch-and-torch-geo)

Answer (score 1):

I check the attached code. It seems that you only inclue the parameters of the `model` into the optimizer.

Make sure you input weights of both models to the optimizers. In your case, for example

```
gin_encoder = GinEncoder().to("cuda")
model =  MainModel(gin_encoder).to("cuda")

opt_enc = torch.optim.Adam(gin_encoder.parameters())
opt_model = torch.optim.Adam(model .parameters())
```

In addtion, make sure you run both optimizers during training, i.e.,

```
opt_enc.zero_grad()
opt_model.zero_grad()

loss.backward()

opt_enc.step()
opt_model.step()
```

Alternatively, you can compose a list that contains the parameters of both models and input it to a single optimizer.

```
opt_merge = torch.optim.Adam(list(model.parameters())+list(gin_encoder.parameters()))
```